# Употребление частицы "ТАК" в начале предложения

Tags: частицы

Уважаемые знатоки русского языка! Прошу пояснить какой смысловой оттенок вносит частица "ТАК" в нижеуказанных предложениях:

1. Садись за руль. **Так** у меня прав нет!
2. Поехали в город. **Так** поздно же уже.
3. Любишь ее? **Так** иди и скажи ей об этом.
4. **Так** выпьем же за дружбу!

Answer (score 2):

В первом и втором случаях (1. и 2.) заменяет <strike>частицу</strike> союз "Но" или словосочетание "Но ведь".

1. Садись за руль. **Но (ведь)** у меня прав нет!
2. Поехали в город. **Но (ведь)** поздно же уже!

В третьем и четвёртом случае заменяет наречие "Тогда" или фразу "в таком случае".

3. Любишь её? **Тогда** иди и скажи ей об этом. (**В таком случае** иди и скажи ей об этом.).
4. **В таком случае** выпьем же за дружбу! (**Тогда** выпьем же за дружбу!).

Comment: *заменяет частицу "Но"* - *Но* - не частица, а союз. Здесь это важно, поскольку "так" тоже союз. В остальном - согласен.

Comment: Может быть "так" отчасти и заменяет "но, ведь", но не полностью. Разница есть, но в чем эта разница - вот в чем вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

"Так" - слово многофункциональное, согласно БТС Кузнецова может быть не только частицей, но и союзом, вводным словом, наречием и, вероятно, даже междометием.

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA

Частица - вообще довольно редкий случай.

> Садись за руль. Так у меня прав нет!
> Поехали в город. Так поздно же уже.

**Так** здесь союз, синонимичный ***но, однако***.

> Любишь ее? Так иди и скажи ей об этом.

**Так** здесь местоименное наречие в значении "в таком случае", "тогда".

> Так выпьем же за дружбу!

Вот здесь еще можно трактовать **"так"** как усилительную частицу - если фраза произнесена отдельно, без связи с предыдущим (застолье - оно такое), но в контексте все же больше напоминает наречие с тем же значением, что и в предыдущем случае.

Comment: Если "так" синонимично "но, однако", то почему употребляют именно "так"?

Comment: Потому что "так" более общая частица-союз чем "но, постойте". "Но, постойте" уже включает внутрь себя противопоставление. "Так" не включает его в себя изначально. Противопоставление получается само по себе из контекста. А "так" лишь усиливает его эффект.

Answer (score 1):

Союзы связывают предложение с предыдущим контекстом. А частицы позволяют добавить восклицательность к предложению(слову) в виде слова, что в устной речи немаловажно. Уж не знаю должны ли быть восклицательные знаки в (2) и (3). Собственно и всё, дополнительного смыслового оттенка частица-союз *так* не несет (смысловой оттенок противопоставление/подтверждение появляется просто по логике разговора):

1. Садись за руль. Раз **так**ое дело, послушайте: у меня прав нет!
2. Поехали в город. Раз **так**ое дело, послушайте: поздно же уже.
3. Любишь ее? Раз **так**ое дело, послушай: иди и скажи ей об этом.
4. Раз **так**ое дело, послушайте: выпьем же за дружбу!

"Раз такое дело" -  принимает предыдущий контекст (противопоставляя ему следующее предложение в 1,2 или подтверждая его следующим предложением в 3,4), выступает в роли союза.
"Послушайте" - усиливает восклицание или просто обращает внимание, выступает в роли частицы.

Comment: Согласен, что "так" принимает предыдущий контекст. Но не во всех примерах "так"  = раз такое дело. Есть разница. В моем понимании "так" - слово обобщитель. И оно указывает на ситуацию в целом с учетом предыдущего высказывания.

Comment: Это "так" - то обобщитель? Скорее конкретизатор. "Так" цепляется к предыдущему контексту и привязывает к нему некий, логически следующий из него конкретный нюанс. Любишь? Так что же не идешь? За руль? Так у меня же прав нет. Итп.